# Python web scraping - Why always getting home page source code?

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping, python-requests

I have done all initial steps to login, able to access the website,
I'm trying to simulate one search operation using a POST request (actually done using submit action form on the web portal), the operation is successful but the page source which I got is from "Home" page.

I can understand if the 100% page source code is not displayed in page source (assuming data generated using `JavaScript`), but here response page is static "Home" page.

**What is redirecting to the home page? How to stop that navigation?**

Here are the code steps to achieve this:

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.get(access_config['login-url'])
session.post(access_config["auth-url"], data=auth_config)
res = session.post(link)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.history)
print(res.url)
print(res.text)
```

response:

```
status code :: 200

history :: <html><head><title>302 Moved Temporarily</title></head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<p>This document you requested has moved 
temporarily.</p>
<p>It's now at <a href="https://www.xxxx.com/a/welcome.html">https://www.xxxx.com/a/welcome.html</a>.</p>
</body></html>

response URL :: https://www.xxxx.com/a/welcome.html
```

I'm using `requests` library, I know lot of people using `selenium` library for these operations, is there anything which I could do this thing using `requests` or other than `selenium`?

Comment: The response doesn't seems Home Page but a redirection page. You have to add a condition for redirection page and get the URL of redirected page from response HTML anchor tag and again make the http call.

Comment: @SonalBorkar Thanks! will try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SonalBorkar Thanks! again

I have inspected using "Firefox inspector" and discovered the 2 requests behind the seen, you can see in pic. 
[image]

Below code worked perfectly -

```
import requests

session = requests.Session()
session.get(access_config['login-url'])
session.post(access_config["auth-url"], data=auth_config)
session.post(link1)
res = session.get(link2)
print(res.status_code)
print(res.history)
print(res.url)
print(res.text)
```

`link1` and `link2` were visible after double click on inspector's row

`link1` --> double click on `search.html`

`link2` --> double click on `seriessearch.html?...`